# how to access user profile info on Login in Social Connect Module in Sitecore

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore-social-connected

I'm using Social Connect Module in Sitecore and using its Login functionality to get user info. The documentation states that the info is stored in the Core DB in aspnet_Profile table. "By default, the module saves the information from the social network in the fields with the corresponding prefixes. For example, fb is a prefix for Facebook fields." - this is the line in the doc. 
However, i cant find such fields in the DB. Or should i be looking somewhere else?

I just want to see what info i'm receiving when the user logs in and would like to have access to it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say database, are you then checking the database using the Sitecore Shell and then switching to Core database or are you actually looking at the ASP.NET Membershipprovider tables in the database using SQL Management Studio?

You should be able to see the records in the table aspnet_Profile. The properties are stored kind of weird and is concatenated in the PropertyValuesStrings column.

You can also use the API to try and retrieve the values as described here: http://learnsitecore.cmsuniverse.net/Developers/Articles/2009/11/Custom%20user%20profile%20properties.aspx

More or less you have to call userProfile.GetCustomProperty(“fb[some property]”);

Comment: Yes @Jen, my aspnet_Profile table showed the username properly but i was confused about the rest of the values. Your right, there is weird binary data in the PropertyValuesStrings column.

Answer (score 1):

You could also take a look at the this blog: [Social Connected with Sitecore (Facebook) 2: Access facebook information](http://techmusingz.wordpress.com/2014/07/03/social-connected-with-sitecore-facebook-2-access-facebook-information/)
This also gives you a sample of looping through all facebook properties from Core.